# How do I reference the android documentation?

Tags: java, android

Its sort of programming related.
Im doing an assignment and I used the android documentation to get information. My question is I use the Harvard style reference and I need to provide an author? So my question is who do I state as the author?

At the moment I am stating
Google, Android (no date) blah blah blah

By android documentation i mean like this one

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Harvard style should have something for an online resource published by an organization and/or with no author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the APA style guide, you'd do something like this:

Google. (n.d.). Retrieved April 29, 2011 from the Android Developer Website: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: Thank you greg, so its ok to put Google as the author?

Comment: Yes, since the Android dev pages are maintained by an organization versus an individual. The legal page here (http://developer.android.com/legal.html) identifies that the site is subject to Google's privacy policy, so they would be considered the authoring organization.